# Sending cookie from server to browser using express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am a computer science student and have been working on login with express.js for hours on XAMPP but couldn't find solutions. 
Here's my idea.
A user types userid and password and sends it through the server using jquery post method. Then, the server will check if id and password match and will send a temporary cookie storing the userid so the browser knows who or status signed in. However, I can't send this cookie to the browser from the server. I would really appreciate your input on this code or my idea.

```
// Variables
var portNum = 3000;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');


app.post('/login',function (req, res) {
    console.log("LOGIN");
    res.cookie('test', 'testValue');
    res.send();
})

var server = app.listen(portNum, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Comment: When it comes to security, I would advice you to use an already working solution with a strong community, e.g. [Express Session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks. You learn something new every day. Do you have any input on the advice I just gave?

Comment: @Tholle - seems to be good advice - better to leverage some code than start from scratch AS LONG AS YOU UNDERSTAND THAT code and what it does before you put it in YOUR solution that you are responsible for.

Comment: @dojon - it almost sounds like you want third party authentication and then  save a cookie of that (for some period) - see what this site does with a Google ID etc. (login using xxx)